# CSS mobile menu design

Tags: css, wordpress, menu

I'm designing my page mobile friendly menu in Wordpress. I want expandable submenus to have + next to them. I'm trying to use *content* to add + next to it and float middle with padding but my issue is I'm getting + next to everything on the menu.

PHP:

```
       <div class="store-menu">
            <div class="store-wrapper">
                <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( '', 'eightstore-lite' ); ?></button>
                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
                </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
   .sub-menu {display: none !important;}

   .menu li a::after{
     content:'+' !important;
     color:'white' !important;
     float:middle !important;
     font-size:14px !important;
     padding-left: 10px !important;

   }
}
```

[image: This is what I want]

This is what i want

Comment: where is the html?

Comment: @mlegg since Wordpress mixed everything it's difficult to track down everything single code. but I'm adding PHP code in my post.

Comment: Can you share your website link?

Comment: https://www.haultfoods.com

Answer (score 0):

Hey so the first little bump your going to run into is that there is no float middle property. You could use flexbox for this, or just a simple text-align: center

Im guessing your other issue is that you only want the '+' icons to show on menu items that have children?

What you need to do in that case is take advantage of the 'menu-item-has-children' classes added by Wordpress to menus. Something like:

```
   .menu li.menu-item-has-children a::after{
     content:'+' !important;
     color:'white' !important;
     text-align: center;
     font-size:14px !important;
     padding-left: 10px !important;
   }
```

Something else to point out is that are misusing the !important property. You will want to look into css specificity [CSS Tricks - css specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying, menu-item-has-children class did help but I'm still getting + next to children.